# Can I create a new type based on the elements of an array in typescript?

Tags: typescript

If now I have an array `keys`:

```
const keys = ['firstname', 'lastname']
```

Can I map all the items as the key of `NewType` like this below?

```
type NewType = {
  firstname: any
  lastname: any
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to use `as const` syntax to tell TS your array values won't change:

```
const keys = ['firstname', 'lastname'] as const;
```

Then you can create a union type from the array values:

```
type Union = typeof keys[number]; // type Union = "firstname" | "lastname"
```

And then use mapped types to create the NewType like so:

```
type Obj = {
    [k in Union]: any;
}

// type Obj = {
//     firstname: any;
//     lastname: any;
// }

const obj: Obj = {
    firstname: '',
    lastname: ''
}
```

Comment: A little shorthand you could use -> `type Obj = Record<typeof keys[number], any>;`

Comment: @Keith I know, I just wanted to explain it step by step so it's easier to understand to the person that has asked the question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's fine.  But for anybody coming across this post, it might help to also show the Record type, as it's a tad easier to reason with.  Showing how to do it manually is certainly not a bad thing to show too :)

Comment: the `as const` syntax is really helpful, thanks, nice guys!